# Riverpod 2.0 FutureProvider correct usage

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

i have a dictionary JSON file that i want to load just one time when my application starts and i'm not sure about how i should do that. My first approach was doing this

```
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
class AppDictionary extends _$AppDictionary {
  @override
  FutureOr<List<DictionaryEntry>> build() async {
    return await _parseDictionary();
  }

  Future<List<DictionaryEntry>> _parseDictionary() async {
    try {
      final response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/dict.json');
      final data = await json.decode(response) as List<dynamic>;
      final parsedData = data
          .map((e) => DictionaryEntry.fromMap(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
          .toList();

      return parsedData;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

And in my initial page i did this

```
final asyncDictionary = ref.watch(appDictionaryProvider);

if (asyncDictionary.isLoading) {
  return const Scaffold(
    body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
  );
}
```

And it is working fine. But reading about FutureProvider in Riverpod's documentation, i saw that i could do it this way

```
@riverpod
Future<List<DictionaryEntry>> loadDictionary(LoadDictionaryRef ref) async {
  try {
    final response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/dict.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response) as List<dynamic>;
    final parsedData = data
        .map((e) => DictionaryEntry.fromMap(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();

    return parsedData;
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
    rethrow;
  }
}
```

And the second way also worked, so i'm wondering which approach is the best. Also, the second way, everytime i call `ref.watch( )` will it load it again? Or once it's loaded it will not run again?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first way is a class-based provider, creating a visible Notifier subclass to manage the state as well as provide possible mutation methods to update that state.

The second way is a function-based provider, creating a hidden Notifier subclass to manage the state, but does *not* provide a place to put mutation methods to update the state.  You would use this when the notifier is based on inputs from other external inputs, rather than being driven by method calls to trigger mutations.  Examples of this strategy *without* using the generator would be Provider, FutureProvider, and StreamProvider.